# Magento Product Listing Sorting Problems

Tags: magento

If I want to sort a list of results by Name Ascending, Magento REMEMBERS this preference and sorts all future ‘Searches’ and ‘Root Categories’ by Name Ascending, even though this isn’t appropriate for Searches… You always want Relevance to be the default.

How is this changed so Magento forgets the Sort Preference?

Answer (score 0):

Magento stores category sorting data, except for the page number, in the catalog session.  Both this session data and URL `GET` arguments are used when applying category sorting, with `GET` arguments being preferred if they exist (which then update the recorded session data).  Sorting data is pulled from the session as follows:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getSortOrder();
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getSortDirection();
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getDisplayMode();
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getLimitPage();
```

You can also unset this session data with the following commands:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->unsSortOrder();
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->unsSortDirection();
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->unsDisplayMode();
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->unsLimitPage();
```

If you search the codebase for these commands it quickly turns up the toolbar class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar` which contains the methods:

```
getCurrentOrder()
getCurrentDirection()
getCurrentMode()
getLimit()
```

Each method pulls the relevant sorting data first by looking at the request parameters (so `GET` argument), if that fails it looks at the session, and finally falls back to default sorting settings if there is no session data.  Note also that there is a call to `$this->_memorizeParam(...);` if a `GET` argument is found which isn't the default sorting for that parameter.

For minimal impact on core functionality, I would suggest your best approach would be something along the lines of rewriting the above methods, and within the new method call the relevant session method as above to unset the session data for that parameter, and finish by calling the parent method with `parent::`.  That way session data would never be found and only URL arguments or default sorting would ever be used.  An example rewrite would be something like this in your module `config.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_ModuleName>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Namespace_ModuleName>
    </modules>
    ....
    <global>
        ...
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_list_toolbar>Namespace_ModuleName_Block_Product_List_Toolbar</product_list_toolbar>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

And your rewritten class:

```
<?php
class Namespace_ModuleName_Block_Product_List_Toolbar extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
{
    public function getCurrentOrder()
    {
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->unsSortOrder();
        parent::getCurrentOrder();
    }

    public function getCurrentDirection()
    {
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->unsSortDirection();
        parent::getCurrentDirection();
    }

    public function getCurrentMode()
    {
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->unsDisplayMode();
        parent::getCurrentMode();
    }

    public function getLimit()
    {
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->unsLimitPage();
        parent::getLimit();
    }
}
```